# @Prop decorator for specific nested objects in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have an array of objects that returns in JSON, each object looks like that:

```
{
  "reviewId": "f1a0ec26-9aca-424f-8b05-cff6aa3d2337",
  "authorName": "Some name",
  "comments": [
    {
      "userComment": {
        "text": "\tAmazing!",
        "lastModified": {
          "seconds": "1659685904",
        },
        "starRating": 5,
        "reviewerLanguage": "en",
      }
    },
    {
      "developerComment": {
        "text": "Thank you.",
        "lastModified": {
          "seconds": "1659688852",
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a Schema for this specific object, but I have some issues and I cannot understand how to create it, this is what i've done so far:

```
import mongoose, { Document, Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export type ReviewDocument = Review & Document;

@Schema()
export class Review {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
    reviewId: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    authorName: string;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array })
    comments: Comments[];
}

@Schema()
export class Comments {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId })
    userComment: UserComment;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId })
    developerComment: DeveloperComment;
}

@Schema()
export class UserComment {
    @Prop({ type: String })
    text: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    originalText: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    lastModified: string;

    @Prop({ type: Number })
    starRating: number;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    reviewerLanguage: string;
}

@Schema()
export class DeveloperComment {
    @Prop({ type: String })
    text: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    lastModified: string;
}

export const ReviewSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Review);
```

It gives me an error:

```
/.../rtr-backend/src/schemas/reviews.schema.ts:21
    userComment: UserComment;
                 ^
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'UserComment' before initialization
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.../rtr-backend/src/schemas/reviews.schema.ts:21:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.../rtr-backend/src/reviews/reviews.module.ts:6:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
```

What is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to notice when you define a mongoose schema:

1. The schema types of primitive properties (e.g. `string`, `number`) are automatically inferred, so you don't need to explicitly specify `{ type: String}` in the decorator.
2. In order to preserve the nested schema validation, each object has to have its own schema or be defined using the `raw` schema definition.
3. For each nested schema please mind the default properties created by mongoose, such as `timestamps`, `_id`, `__v`, and so on. You could manipulate them by passing options object in the `@Schema()` decorator.

Here is the schema definition for your use case:

```js
import { Prop, raw, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ _id: false })
class UserComment {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  text: string;

  @Prop(raw({ seconds: { type: Number } }))
  lastModified: Record<string, number>;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  starRating: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  reviewerLanguage: string;
}
const UserCommentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(UserComment);

@Schema({ _id: false })
class DeveloperComment {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  text: string;

  @Prop(raw({ seconds: { type: Number } }))
  lastModified: Record<string, number>;
}

const DeveloperCommentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(DeveloperComment);

@Schema({ _id: false })
class Comment {
  @Prop({ type: UserCommentSchema })
  userComment?: UserComment;

  @Prop({ type: DeveloperCommentSchema })
  developerComment?: DeveloperComment;
}

const CommentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Comment);

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class Review {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Prop({ unique: true, required: true })
  reviewId: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  authorName: string;

  @Prop({ type: [CommentSchema], default: [] })
  comments: Comment[];
}

export type ReviewDocument = Review & Document;
export const ReviewSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Review);
```

PS: In this documentation page you could find plenty of use cases: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to first define the schemas in the order of their dependencies, like this:

```
import mongoose, { Document, Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export type ReviewDocument = Review & Document;

@Schema()
export class UserComment {
    @Prop({ type: String })
    text: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    originalText: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    lastModified: string;

    @Prop({ type: Number })
    starRating: number;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    reviewerLanguage: string;
}

@Schema()
export class DeveloperComment {
    @Prop({ type: String })
    text: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    lastModified: string;
}

@Schema()
export class Comments {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId })
    userComment: UserComment;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId })
    developerComment: DeveloperComment;
}

@Schema()
export class Review {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
    reviewId: string;

    @Prop({ type: String })
    authorName: string;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array })
    comments: Comments[];
}

export const ReviewSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Review);
```